# What linking typescript with npm means?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, linker, webpack-dev-server

I have following typescript files which I am trying to build using webpack. When I executed webpack for first time, I got an error:

```
08/12/2017  17:18                39 a.ts
08/12/2017  17:18                39 b.ts
10/12/2017  10:03    <DIR>          node_modules
08/12/2017  17:15               160 test.ts
09/12/2017  19:42               317 tsconfig.json
10/12/2017  10:15               212 webpack.config.js

C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\typescript>webpack
Hash: ca89239394c5fd4255d7
Version: webpack 3.3.0
Time: 281ms
      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./bundle.js  2.73 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./test.ts 254 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./test.ts
Module build failed: Could not load TypeScript. Try installing with `yarn add typescript` or `npm install typescript`. If TypeScript is installed globally, try using `yarn link typescript` or `npm link typescript`.

C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\typescript>npm link typescript
C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\typescript\node_modules\typescript -> 
C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript

C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\typescript>webpack
Hash: 81b7d03586b8d82eefd3
Version: webpack 3.3.0
Time: 2375ms
      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./bundle.js  2.66 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./test.ts 187 bytes {0} [built]
```

I executed the `npm link typescript` command and things worked. However, I do not understand why I had to run the link command?

Comment: In my case this problem went away when I installed typescript both globally and localy but maybe link does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

> I executed the npm link typescript command and things worked. However, I do not understand why I had to run the link command

Its worked because TypeScript is installed globally

i.e. you (or someone on your machine) ran something like `npm install typescript -g`.

## More

Docs : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link